# Is this compiler bug triggered by invalid code, or should it compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++, g++4.8

Given the following complete program:

```
#include <functional>

struct jobbie
{
    std::function<void()> a;
};

void do_jobbie(jobbie j = {})
{
    if (j.a) 
        j.a();
}

int main()
{
    do_jobbie();
    return 0;
}
```

compiling this on gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1:
boom!

```
richard@DEV1:~/tmp$ g++ -std=c++11 bug.cpp
bug.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
bug.cpp:16:13: internal compiler error: in create_tmp_var, at gimplify.c:479
  do_jobbie();
             ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/ccWGpb7M.out file, please attach this to your bugreport.
```

However, clang [Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)] is happy with it.

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 bug.cpp
```

It seems to me that clang is correctly deducing that j defaults to a default-constructed `jobbie` object whereas gcc is (obviously) blowing up.

replacing line 8 with `void do_jobbie(jobbie j = jobbie {})` fixes the problem on gcc.

Question - which of these is true:

1. clang is correct, gcc is faulty (ignoring the compiler blow-up)
2. clang is over-reaching the standard and it should not really compile
3. the standard does not make it clear?

Comment: I am getting a linker error, `g++4.9` OS X. `clang++` compiles and links it though.

Comment: An **ICE**, internal compiler error, is always a bug in the compiler. No matter if it's triggered by invalid code. Report it.

Comment: g++4.9 seems to fail to instantiate `std::function<void()>` for some reason; adding a `std::function<void()> a;` in `main()` eliminates the linker error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicates that it should work:

> The default argument has the same semantic constraints as the initializer in a declaration of a variable of the parameter type, using the copy-initialization semantics.

(8.3.6, wording from draft n3936)

Comment: ok thanks for that. Next question then - what is the easiest way to get a working copy of clang++ 3.4 on an ubuntu 12.04 system :)

Comment: @RichardHodges: I'd be very surprised if there was any easier way than `apt-get` (possibly adding or updating repositories before using `apt-get install`)

Comment: @RichardHodges: [looks helpful: "The goal is to provide Debian and Ubuntu nightly packages ready to be installed with minimal impact on the distribution.
Packages are available for amd64 and i386 and for both the stable and development branches (currently 3.4 and 3.5)."](http://llvm.org/apt/)

Comment: do you have a link for that?

Answer (score 4):

An internal compiler error is always a compiler bug. Compilers should be able to process anything without crashing like that.

clang has similar handling for when it crashes, producing data for reporting the bug and pointing the user to clang's bug reporting web page.

I don't see anything tricky about this code. It seems straightforward to me that it should compile and run.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am of course aware that the compiler should not barf, but that's not really the question I am asking. The question really is, "is it correct to ask the compiler to deduce the type of the default parameter, since I only provided an initialiser list and not a type specifier".

Comment: It doesn't have to deduce anything, `jobbie j = {}` is perfectly explicit about what `{}` is.